# bootstrap accordion rerouting when a button in accordion-heading is clicked

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

I have this below code

```
<uib-accordion close-others="true" class="my-table">
            <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="column-header accordion-heading">
                    <div class="accordion-toggle">
                        <div class="accordion-cell">column1</div>
                        <div class="accordion-cell">column2</div>
                        <div class="accordion-cell">Remove</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <uib-accordion-group ng-repeat="row in parentRows">
                <uib-accordion-heading class="accordion-heading">
                    <div ng-click="loadAccordionContent(row)" class="accordion-row">
                        <div class="accordion-cell">{{row.col1Val }}</div>
                        <div class="accordion-cell">{{row.col2Val }}</div>
                        <div class="accordion-cell">
                            <button type="button" ng-click="removeRow(row)"
                                    class="btn btn-sm cat-remove-button">
                                Remove
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">
                                </i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </uib-accordion-heading>

                <div>Some dynamic content</div>
            </uib-accordion-group>
        </uib-accordion>
```

When I click the button this code is rerouting to my app's home page. Why would that be? I am expecting it to call removeRow(row) which removes that row and updates parentRows.

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
removeRow(row)
```

to

```
removeRow(row, $event)
```

and adding this below code in the beginning of my function solved this issue

```
        if ($event) {
        $event.stopPropagation();
        $event.preventDefault();
    }
```